# Different behaviour of `DateRange` between 11.2 and 11.3

Tags: bugs, date-and-time

**Bug introduced in 11.3 and fixed in 12.0.**

> CASE:4028568

---

```
DateRange[DateObject[{2018, 1, 1}, TimeObject[{0, 0, 0}]], 
          DateObject[{2018, 1, 1}, TimeObject[{4, 0, 0}]], {1, "Hours"}]
```

returns:

11.3

```
{DateObject[{2018, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 0.], 
 DateObject[{2018, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 0.], 
 DateObject[{2018, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 0.], 
 DateObject[{2018, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 0.]}
```

11.2

```
{DateObject[{2018, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 0.], 
 DateObject[{2018, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 0.], 
 DateObject[{2018, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 0.], 
 DateObject[{2018, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 0.], 
 DateObject[{2018, 1, 1, 4, 0, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 0.]}
```

11.3 is missing the last entry compared to 11.2 - could anyone confirm ?

Comment: Cloud is now on 11.3 and `CloudEvaluate` does confirm this.

Comment: Confirmed bug: CASE:4028568.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is indeed dropping the last element. One way around this behavior(at least until the issue is fixed) is to have the end-point of the range not be an "Instant" date(ie: drop the final 0 in the list):

```
    DateRange[DateObject[{2018, 1, 1}, TimeObject[{0, 0, 0}]], 
     DateObject[{2018, 1, 1}, TimeObject[{4, 0}]], {1, "Hours"}]

    {DateObject[{2018, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", -5.], 

     DateObject[{2018, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", -5.], 

     DateObject[{2018, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", -5.], 

     DateObject[{2018, 1, 1, 3, 0, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", -5.], 

     DateObject[{2018, 1, 1, 4, 0, 0.}, "Instant", "Gregorian", -5.]}
```